# Is the wave velocity of sound waves in a medium constant?

Tags: waves, velocity, frequency

I am giving a few parameters to explain my question:

If I consider two waves A and B in a medium under same conditions of density and pressure, and

If I suppose that:

Wave A has a velocity of 100 ms/s and has a frequency 5000 Hz.

Then does the wave B also have a velocity of 100 m/s?
In that case could I use 100 ms/s to calculate the frequency of the wave B?

I would be helped if you could explain this.

Answer (score 2):

By the Newton-Laplace equation for velocity of sound waves which is:

$c=\sqrt\frac{B}{\rho}$
where
B: Modulus of elasticity of medium
$\rho$: Density of medium

---

Since we're keeping the density and pressure same, hence the velocity of the sound wave indeed would be constant.
Also as we know the general formula for velocity of waves,
$v=f\lambda$  (where f is the frequency and $\lambda$ is the wavelength)
would also be constant

Hence in this situation, for any two waves A and B,
$f_{A}\lambda_{A} = f_{B}\lambda_{B}$